# How to receive data from multiple channels in sequence?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I am currently trying to receive data from two channels using a select statement.

```golang
select {
    case msg1 := <-ch1:
        // send to another channel
    case msg2 := <-ch2:
        // send to another channel
}
```

The format of the data received from the above two channels is as follows.

```golang
type msg struct {
    msgId uint32
    data []byte
}
```

What I want is to compare the `msg` received from two channels with `msgId` and send `msg` to another channel in order.

Is the only way to achieve my goal is to use `sync.Mutex` to use the data structure Queue?

Is there a way to send the data sent through a channel from multiple goroutines back to another channel in order?

**EDIT**: The data coming from the two channels is sorted as long as the order is correct. Data is not transmitted in a completely jumbled order.

Comment: In what _order_? `select` picks a random "available" `case`: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements

Comment: You can order messages coming from two channels, and send them to another channel. You wouldn't need a mutex. However you have to store all out-of-order messages, and for that you should know how many you can store.

Comment: @zerkms
For example, if `msg`s 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9 are transmitted from `ch1`, and `msg`s 4, 5, 6 are transmitted from `ch2`, 1, I want to send `msg` in the order of 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to another channel.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Are you saying that after receiving all the data to be received from two channels, sorting all the received data and then sending it to the other channel? 
However, in the current situation, there is no way to know the number of data coming from those two channels.

Comment: "after receiving all the data to be received from two channels, sorting all the received data and then sending it to the other channel" --- are the messages pre-sorted in each source channel? Are there gaps between messages IDs?

Comment: @zerkms 
right. The text has also been modified, but as in the previous example, the data transmitted in each channel are in a sorted state, and I just want to send them in one channel again in the same order. Also do not overlap.

Comment: Let's say from one channel you received message 10 while you are expecting 1. That means you have to buffer all messages until you receive 1. If you are sure you will eventually receive 1, you can buffer everything in between, and send them in order to another channel.

Comment: @BurakSerdar So, is there no way to receive `msg` in order without using another data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an ordering algorithm that buffers out-of-order messages like this:

```
// Buffer to keep out-of-order messages
buffer:=make(map[uint32]msg)
// id of the next expected message
nextExpected:=1 
for {
  select {
      case m:=<-ch1:
        buffer[m.id]=m
      case m:=<-ch2:
        buffer[m.id]=m
  }
  // If the next expected message is received, send it
  for {
     if m,ok:=buffer[nextExpected]; ok {
        result<-m
        delete(buffer,nextExpected)
        nextExpected++
     } else {
        break
     }
  }
}
```